# Serve cache on timeout in okhttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

In okhttp3, if my connection times out in CONNECT or READ, is there some way I can get the cache from okhttp? Instead of the connection failing, I want to serve the user from the offline cache in case the request is taking too long.

Comment: see [How does Android OkHttp cache work?](https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/how-does-okhttp-cache-works-851d37dd29cd)

Answer (score 1):

I did experience a similar issue. I wanted to fallback to cache whenever my request was timing out (I don't mind in which state) or when connection is disrupted, or when there is no connection available. To do this I made an interceptor that would first check for connectivity and after that also catch exceptions when making the request. If there is a timeout then it will throw an exception, after which we fallback to an aggressive caching.

So basically, you first need to set up your okhttp client to use cache and then use an interceptor to use that cache in a better way.

```
public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "okHttpCache");
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheFile, CACHE_SIZE);

    ConnectivityInterceptor connectivityInterceptor = new ConnectivityInterceptor(networkStateHelper);
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor);
    return builder.build();
}
```

After that you can use this simple interceptor to force the usage of the cache. Normally the cache is used when the server responds with 340 which means there are no changes so we can take responses that are cached, but this of course needs an active internet connection. We can however force the cache usage so it will directly take any respond from the cache if possible, which comes in handy when you are offline or when you have timeouts

```
public class ConnectivityInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    // NetworkStateHelper is some class we have that checks if we are online or not.
    private final NetworkStateHelper networkStateHelper;

    public ConnectivityInterceptor(NetworkStateHelper networkStateHelper) {
        this.networkStateHelper = networkStateHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        // You can omit this online check or use your own helper class
        if (networkStateHelper.isNotOnline()) {
            return getResponseFromCache(chain, request);
        }
        try {
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return new Pair<>(request, response);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.w(exception, "Network failure discovered, trying cache fallback");
            return getResponseFromCache(chain, request);
        }

    }

    private Response getResponseFromCache(Interceptor.Chain chain,
            Request request) throws IOException {
        // We just create a new request out of the old one and set cache headers to it with the cache control. 
        // The CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE is already provided by OkHttp3
        request = request.newBuilder().cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE).build();

        // Now we proceed with the request and OkHttp should automatically fetch the response from cache or return
        // a failure if it is not there, some 5xx status code
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

}
```